# Android toast by adb

Tags: android, adb, toast

Sorry if there is a duplication but I couldn't find clear answer with updates for last Android versions and so fourth. Im working with Android adb and do some automatization to check apps. I don't have my own app on the device and I would like to avoid using it if possible. What I need to do is on the relatively same time as I send intent to play video by Youtube to generate any actions visible on screen. I thought to use toast but couldn't find proper way to make toast appear on the screen by adb (kind of "now intent to play video has been sent"). Actually it might be something elase allows to identify timestamp of intent sending process but it should be visible on the screen without video interrupting. Thanks for any advice! PS. device is rooted.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without any installed app - but you don't have to create apps for this, as they are in existence already - have a look at this one for example: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=773232

Comment: Thanks Aleks, it works!